# How to match two different image in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to reconstruct a 3D model of a anatomical structure. So I want to match key points in pair of X ray images. I tried it by using following code. But it didn't give correct results.

```
Mat tmp = cv::imread( "1.jpg", 1 );
Mat in  = cv::imread( "2.jpg", 1 );
cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector( 0.0001, 1.0 );
cv::SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector.detect( tmp, keypoints1 );
detector.detect( in, keypoints2 );

Mat feat1,feat2;
drawKeypoints(tmp,keypoints1,feat1,Scalar(255, 255, 255),DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
drawKeypoints(in,keypoints2,feat2,Scalar(255, 255, 255),DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
imwrite( "feat1.bmp", feat1 );
imwrite( "feat2.bmp", feat2 );
int key1 = keypoints1.size();
int key2 = keypoints2.size();
printf("Keypoint1=%d \nKeypoint2=%d", key1, key2);

Mat descriptor1,descriptor2;
extractor.compute( tmp, keypoints1, descriptor1 );
extractor.compute( in, keypoints2, descriptor2 );

BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> > matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;

matcher.match( descriptor1, descriptor2, matches );
double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

Mat img_matches;
for( int i = 0; i < descriptor1.rows; i++ )
{ double dist = matches[i].distance;
if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptor1.rows; i++ )
{ if( matches[i].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 0.03) )
{ good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
}

drawMatches( tmp, keypoints1, in, keypoints2,
           good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
           vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );


namedWindow("SIFT", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow("SIFT", img_matches);
imwrite("sift_1.jpg",img_matches);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

These are the two images

[image: image 01]

[image: image 02]

This is what i got from this code

[image: Result image]

This is very close to my expected result but it also matching wrong points. This shows few points but i need more points.

[image]

Comment: In what way are the results incorrect? What results are you expecting? You should provide a [mcve] and clarify your question.

Comment: hashmap is very fast to check if two images are same or not. But both images have to match perfectly which in many cases are not.

Comment: @GregKikola As you can see result is matching sharp points wrongly. you can see the line are crossed the each other. anyway i will add a image which i expect.

Comment: You method would work perfectly only for colored images. Such technique cannot be applicable for binary images

Comment: I don't know much about how OpenCV does this, but if you maybe only gave it the top third of the two images, then the middle third, then the final third (with some overlap), it would have fewer opportunities to make *"incorrect"* matches. Just a thought - but it is somewhat based on the hopefully correct assumption that you do have some *a priori* knowledge that you are not currently sharing with the matcher.

Answer (score 2):

Feature detectors like SIFT or SURF are designed to work and match images that have a rich and distinctive texture. They are not designed to work with very spares binary inputs like your examples.

You might want to try them on the original X-Rays for more image context.
Alternatively, you might try a more direct global alignment model between the images.

Check out [this link](http://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/) for some options for alignment with the [`findTransformECC()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga7ded46f9a55c0364c92ccd2019d43e3a) function.

Also see [the article here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/24809/image-alignment-algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to use ITK, ITK is designed to complete image registration with 2D or 3D images.